# Oracle - Use of Between with letters - Between 'A' and 'C'

Tags: oracle11g, between, letter

this doubt is very basic, however, after reading an answer for a given question I got fairly confused (I don't know why as it is a simple subject).

Consider this basic query:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ename BETWEEN ‘A’ AND ‘C’
```

The employees name returned will be those whose names start with A and B, and the explanation is as follows:

> Here, a character column is compared against a string using the
>   BETWEEN operator,  which is equivalent to ename >= ‘A’ AND ename <**=**
>   ‘C’. The name CLARK will not be  included in this query, because
>   ‘CLARK’ is > ‘C’.

Why is Clark considered greater than 'C' if in the explanation we have the statement: *ename is less than or **equal** to 'C'* ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you alphabetically sort

```
Constant Clark C Claude
```

you'll get

```
C Clark Claude Constant
```

so

```
C < Clark < Claude < Constant
```

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation#Alphabetical_order) for a more formal explanation, the essence is this (emphasis mine):

> To decide which of two strings comes first in alphabetical order,
>   initially their first letters are compared. The string whose first
>   letter appears earlier in the alphabet comes first in alphabetical
>   order. If the first letters are the same, then the second letters are
>   compared, and so on, until the order is decided. (**If one string runs
>   out of letters to compare, then it is deemed to come first; for
>   example, "cart" comes before "carthorse".**) The result of arranging a
>   set of strings in alphabetical order is that words with the same first
>   letter are grouped together, and within such a group words with the
>   same first two letters are grouped together and so on.

Comment: Thank you, it is funny that I applied the correct sorting in some exercises just like as you mentioned but the Between for some reason got me a bit confused, thanks once more. edit: too bad I cannot mark the answer as useful (no sufficient reputation yet).

Answer (score 0):

**Why is Clark considered greater than 'C' if in the explanation we have the statement: ename is less than or equal to 'C' ?**

There is one thing to consider here.For obvious reasons we have ALLEN,BLAKE,CLARK,ADAMS,A,C.Sorting alphabetically we have

*A
ADAMS
ALLEN
BLAKE
C*
CLARK

That's why CLARK IS NOT PART OF THE RANGE BECAUSE IT COMES AFTER C.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  No need to shout though.